# XCode4 Tab bar template problem

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I'm starting using XCode4 and when I tried to make new project with tab bar app template, I figured out that I can't select my tab bar to add new tabs. I can't drag-drop tab bar item from objects library and I can't select tab bar to get properties in inspector.

How to do this in XCode4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your MainWindow.xib, expand your tab bar controller, select one of your view controllers and copy/paste.